# Out of memory when loading background images of button array

Tags: c#

I am trying to load an array of images from a database and set the background image for an array of buttons.

I seem to "run out of memory" when loading the background image of a button. I tried this method with picture boxes (instead of buttons), and it works.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Button[] pb = { pictureButton1, pictureButton2, pictureButton3, pictureButton4, pictureButton5,
        pictureButton6, pictureButton7, pictureButton8, pictureButton9, pictureButton10, pictureButton11, pictureButton12, pictureButton13,
        pictureButton14, pictureButton15, pictureButton16, pictureButton17, pictureButton18, pictureButton19, pictureButton20, pictureButton21 };


        using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    if (dr["ITEM_Picture"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        byte[] image = (byte[])dr["ITEM_Picture"];
                        stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
                        if (i >= 21)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        pb[i].BackgroundImage = (bitmap);

                    }
                }

                i++;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you really mean to make a copy of `dt["ITEM_Picture"]`?

Comment: are you placing raw images in the db? you really shouldn't if you are, make it a directory to load the image from

Answer (score 3):

You have a few memory leaks:

The line

```
pb[i].BackgroundImage = (bitmap);
```

is making a deep copy of `bitmap`, which I'm not sure is what you want. In either case, your current implementation is creating a bitmap, copying it (which can be resource-intensive and should be avoided - you're allocating something then copying it just for the convenience of having a local label for the new bitmap), and never releasing the memory allocated when you created the current `bitmap` instance.

Try this:

```
using(var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream))
{
    if (i >= pb.Length)
    {
        return;
    }
    pb[i].BackgroundImage = (bitmap);
}
```

If that's not the issue: on which line is the exception thrown?

Also, you really shouldn't be building an array like `pb`. Try iterating through the parent's `Controls` property and checking for `PictureButtons`. Having a hard-coded array like this means that when anyone adds, removes, or renames a control, your loading code must be updated. Also, I hope your database query is ordering the buttons correctly and not relying on insert order.

Also, I have to ask: what happens if you have a different number of `PictureButton`s than rows in the database? This is a very fragile design. (Obviously it won't crash, but images will be ignored, or buttons will be left blank, or, worse, showing whatever image was loaded at the last refresh - stale data).

Answer (score 0):

I just changed:

```
pb[i].BackgroundImage = (bitmap);
```

to

```
pb[i].Image = (bitmap);
```

and it worked.

Comment: Congrats. You're most likely still leaking Memory like a sieve.